# Issue with rake db:migrate whilst setting up pins scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-migrations

I have been having some issues with `rake db:migrate` while setting up a pins scaffold for the One Mont Rails tutorial. When I try to migrate in the terminal I get the following error:

```
Taylors-MacBook-Pro:pinteresting taylorburton$ bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
== 20150410031405 AddUserIdToPins: migrating ==================================
-- add_column(:pins, :user_id, :integer)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: user_id: ALTER TABLE "pins" ADD "user_id" integer/Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
/Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `new'
/Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `prepare'
/Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:134:in `execute'
/Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:333:in `block in execute'
/Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:466:in `block in log'
/Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:460:in `log'
/Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:333:in `execute'
/Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:381:in `add_column'
/Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:458:in `add_column'
/Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:662:in `block in method_missing'
/Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:632:in `block in say_with_time'
/Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:632:in `say_with_time'
/Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:652:in `method_missing'
/Users/taylorburton/Desktop/pinteresting/db/migrate/20150410031405_add_user_id_to_pins.rb:3:in `change'
/Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:606:in `exec_migration'
/Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:590:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:589:in `block in migrate'
/Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:292:in `with_connection'
/Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:588:in `migrate'
/Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:765:in `migrate'
/Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:995:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1041:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:188:in `within_new_transaction'
/Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
/Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1041:in `ddl_transaction'
/Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:994:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:956:in `block in migrate'
/Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `each'
/Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `migrate'
/Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:820:in `up'
/Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:798:in `migrate'
/Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
/Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
-e:1:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
Taylors-MacBook-Pro:pinteresting taylorburton$
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the error message carefully. It says:

```
duplicate column name: user_id: ALTER TABLE "pins" ADD "user_id"
```

This means `user_id` is already present in `pins` table when your migration is being carried out, which was unexpected. Hence the error.

If you drop `user_id` column from `pins` table this error will go  and hopefully migration will succeed. However manually (by this I mean using SQL commands) altering Rails database is not recommended and in fact that itself is very likely to be the reason behind this error in first place.

Alternatively, if you dont care about any existing data, you can also do:

```
rake db:reset
```

Followed by `rake db:migrate`

Comment: Thanks @shivam, I thought that might be part of the issue. Unfortunately that didn't work either. I'm going to destroy the migration and see if the app still works without the user_id functionality as it did before.

Comment: what did you mean by - that didnt work? Did you get the same error again? or a different message?

Comment: well that certainly means the column was not removed properly.

Comment: thanks again @shivam. I will keep you posted when I have a chance to fix this issue. I know there are some issues with this tutorial, as it was originally created with an older version of Rails and so I have had to make a few adjustments along the way. In any case thanks!